# How to show html code as html in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I show HTML code as html code?

This is my code:

```
$body='<h1>Some Text</h1>';
```

My **index.blade.php**

```
{{ $body }}
```

When run:

> <h1>Some Text</h1>

But I want it:

> **Some Text**

How can I show the html code as html code?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of your question (quoting the actual behavior and the expected behavior). You may want to also rephrase it to "_how to show html as **interpreted** html_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try like this

```
 $body='<h1>Some Text</h1>';
```

My **index.blade.php**

```
{!! $body !!}
```

---

**When run**:

It will give as: **Some Text**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
{!! $body !!}
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: @Benyamin Welcome